# Numpy: Select all rows and columns from an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I was hoping I would solve this before I finished the post, but here it goes:

I have an array `array1` with a shape (4808L, 5135L) and I am trying to select a rectangular subset of the array.  Specifically, I am trying to select the all values in rows `4460:4807` and all the values in columns `2718:2967`.

To start I create a mask of the same shape as `array1` like:

```
mask = np.zeros(array1.shape[:2], dtype = "uint8")
mask[array1== 399] = 255
```

Then I am trying to find the index of the points where `mask = 255`:

```
true_points = np.argwhere(mask)
top_left = true_points.min(axis=0)
# take the largest points and use them as the bottom right of your crop
bottom_right = true_points.max(axis=0)
cmask = mask[top_left[0]:bottom_right[0]+1, top_left[1]:bottom_right[1]+1]
```

Where:
    top_left = array([4460, 2718], dtype=int64)
    bottom_right = array([4807, 2967], dtype=int64)

`cmask` looks correct.  Then using `top_left` and `bottom_right` I am trying to subset `array1` using:

```
crop_array = array1[top_left[0]:bottom_right[0]+1, top_left[1]:bottom_right[1]+1]
```

This results in a `crop_array` have the same shape of `cmask`, but the values are populated incorrectly. Since `cmask[0][0] = 0` I would expect `crop_array[0][0]` to be equal to zero as well.

How do I poulate `crop_array` with the values from `array1` while retaining the structure of the `cmask`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't quite get you. Why would you have 4460 on one hand and want 4417 on the other hand?

Comment: @Psidom They both come from a mask.  4460 is the minimum column index where I find my desired value.  4417 is the column associated with the minimum row index where i find my desired value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you're looking for the [.copy()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) method. An example matching your indices and variables:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.random.rand(4808,5135)
crop_array = array1[4417:,2718:2967].copy()

assert np.all(np.equal(array1[4417:,2718:2967], crop_array)) == True, (
    'Equality Failed'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  My problems were something else, but your solution addressed my orignal post